# Can an enemy take a reaction if you target them with a spell while the Time Stop spell is active?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, time, reactions

Say a character casts [*time stop*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/time-stop) on themselves. While the spell is active, they target another creature with a spell (thus ending the *time stop*). Can that targeted character make a reaction to the spell?

For instance, if the caster of *time stop* then cast *finger of death* at the enemy, could the enemy:

1. *Counterspell* it?
2. Try to reduce the damage from it?
3. Retaliate using *hellish rebuke*?

Comment: Related: [Do reactions interrupt their triggers or not?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/117496/do-reactions-interrupt-their-triggers-or-not)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### *Time stop* ends if you "affect" another creature by your actions.

So, in order:

- *Counterspell*, no. That would have to be done before the spell takes effect.
- *Hellish rebuke*, yes. It happens after the damage has been rolled and applied.
- "Try to reduce the damage", depends.

Consider *shield*. As written, it isn't really functional, because it can only be cast after you've been hit, but then can make the attack not hit you, which would imply that it couldn't have been cast.

The sensible interpretation is that when *shield* says you're "hit" by the attack, it means that the attack has been rolled, and *would* hit you, but the attack is not yet a hit; there's still time for some kind of very fast trick that will save you, such as *shield*. And then the attack causes no damage because you never actually got hit.

But if you're being attacked by someone who's cast *time stop*, then their actions have not affected you until you actually do get hit. If *shield* were to make the attack miss, then you'd still be frozen in time, and therefore you couldn't have cast *shield*. So that doesn't work.

On the other hand, *absorb elements* has to be cast after you *take damage*, which suggests it may work. That's right on the edge though; I could see a DM ruling that since it reduces damage from present and future attacks but not from the past, it logically must be cast before the damage happens.

Comment: @Medix2: ...Why are you pinging me to ask that? I'm not the answerer.

Comment: @Medix2 If "creating a situation someone would want to respond to" counted as "affecting" them, then _time stop_ would be pretty useless, wouldn't it? "You moved out of my threatened space, which affects me by allowing me to make an opportunity attack."

Comment: So you contend that an attack against a creature doesn't count as "affecting" it unless it actually hits? Even if that's the case, why does that prevent casting *Shield*, which is triggered on being hit? Wouldn't this logic make *Shield* completely unusable, since it always (when used correctly) un-does its trigger by changing the hit into a miss? (Apologies if this was already discussed in comments that were deleted.)

Comment: @RyanCThompson _Shield_ is unusable as written, for exactly that reason. See further discussion [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/142420/44552). If you think it's useful, I'll add some clarification to this answer.

Comment: @MarkWells Yeah, I think it would help to clarify the exact "timing" of when during the attack *Time Stop* ends. E.g. maybe "the spell ends after the attack is done being resolved and that's too late to cast Shield". (Just an example, I don't know if that's the actual timing.)

Comment: Just note that *shield* is a rather exceptional feature in that it *removes its own trigger*. We actually have quite a lot of questions regarding it some saying [it involves time travel](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122516) ([another example](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/79664) and others disagreeing [whether you've actually been hit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122516) and then some questions that [seem to have an agreed upon answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/105449) which doesn't blend with the idea of *actually* having been hit.

Comment: I'm not sure if you'd want to incorporate any of that into your answer, I just felt I should point out that how the *shield* spell works is... a not well agreed upon mess of a question

Comment: @Medix2 "_Shield_ involves time travel" is a fringe theory, not supported by the text of the spell, and provides no value in answering this question anyway because it's not clear how it would interact with _time stop_, which definitely does involve time travel. (From your perspective, the entire _time stop_ sequence of events happens instantaneously--if you have magic that rewinds time, can you rewind into the middle of that? _Who knows?_)