# Entropic Ward Sneak Attack

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, stealth, reactions

Are you able to entropic ward an attack from stealth? Or would it just be assumed that you didn’t know it was coming therefore you can’t cast a reaction.

For reference the Great Old One Warlock gets the Entropic Ward feature which states:

> [...] When a creature makes an attack roll against you, you can use your reaction to impose disadvantage on that roll. If the attack misses you, your next attack roll against the creature has advantage if you make it before the end of your next turn [...]

Comment: I assume when you say "Sneak Attack" you mean any attack from stealth and not specifically the Rogue's [Sneak Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/rogue#SneakAttack-343) feature? That said, Hello and welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and you can visit the [help] for further guidance. You can reply to comment using @ followed by a username. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Some related questions that might be good for reading: "[Can a Wizard cast Shield in reaction to a stealth attack?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53494)" and "[Can a reaction be used against an attack from a hidden attacker?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/94700)",

Comment: Are you referring to an attack by a hidden creature that has advantage?

Answer (score 5):

### You can use Entropic Ward so long as a creature is making an attack roll and you can take reactions; there are no other requirements.

The feature never says that you have to be able to *see* whoever is attacking you, nor do you have to know where they are, or anything of the sort. The *only* thing required is that a creature be making an attack roll against you, and if this is the case, you may use the feature.

For an example of a feature that uses your reaction and *does* require you to be able to see your opponent there is [*hellish rebuke*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/hellish-rebuke):

> 1 reaction which you take in response to being damaged by a creature within 60 feet of you **that you can see**

---

Here are some scenarios where you wouldn't be able to use Entropic Ward:

1. You used it earlier and have not taken a short or long rest since then.
2. You are currently [surprised](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Surprise) and your turn hasn't come up in initiative:

   > If you're surprised, you can't move or take an action on your first turn of the combat, and **you can't take a reaction until that turn ends.**
3. You are [incapacitated](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/appendix-a-conditions#Incapacitated):

   > An incapacitated creature can't take actions or reactions.

---

### Note that Entropic Ward is used *before* the roll is actually made

This can be shown by comparing the wording of Entropic Ward to that of other features such as the Bard's Cutting Words feature:

> **Entropic Ward:**
>
> When a creature makes an attack roll against you, you can use your reaction to impose disadvantage on that roll.

> **Cutting Words:**
>
> When a creature that you can see within 60 feet of you makes an attack roll [...] you can use your reaction to expend one of your uses of Bardic Inspiration, rolling
>   a Bardic Inspiration die and subtracting the number rolled from the creature’s roll. **You can choose to use this feature after the creature makes its roll**, but before the DM determines whether the attack roll or ability check succeeds or fails [...]

You cannot choose to use Entropic Ward after the creature makes its attack roll, and thus the feature must be used *before* the attack roll is actually made.

---

A small note: Entropic Ward doesn't flatly remove advantage and replace it with disadvantage, it only applies disadvantage to the attack. Since the attacker is hidden they would ordinarily have advantage and due to Entropic Ward would now have both advantage and disadvantage, a scenario about which the rules state this:

> If circumstances cause a roll to have both advantage and disadvantage, you are considered to have neither of them, and you roll one d20. This is true even if multiple circumstances impose disadvantage and only one grants advantage or vice versa. In such a situation, you have neither advantage nor disadvantage.