# How/when does an ability like a dragon's breath weapon recharge, if it's listed as "Recharge 5–6"?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons, breath-weapon, recharge

Dragon breath weapons used to be simple: 3 uses per day. They magically recharged at either midnight or dawn, depending on your DM.

As I read through the dragon section, I see new *(to me)* info on Lair and Legendary actions, environmental effects, and more. Those all seem pretty straight forward. However, when I get to the actual stat blocks for dragons *(for a [Black Dragon](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/ancient-black-dragon))*, I see stuff like:

> ***Acid Breath (Recharge 5–6).***

Did I miss where this was explained? What exactly does this 5-6 mean?

**How/when does an ability like a dragon's breath weapon recharge, if it's listed as "Recharge 5–6"?**

Comment: Related: [Does a “Recharge X-Y” ability need to recharge after it is Readied (but not used)?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128048/does-a-recharge-x-y-ability-need-to-recharge-after-it-is-readied-but-not-used)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is explained under "Limited Usage" on page 11 of the *Monster Manual* or [here in the basic rules on D&D Beyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/monsters#LimitedUsage):

> **Recharge X–Y.** [...] At the start of each of the monster's turns, roll a d6. If the roll is one of the numbers in the recharge notation, the monster regains the use of the special ability. The ability also recharges when the monster finishes a short or long rest. [...]

Comment: That's very straight forward! I hadn't gotten to reading the entire MM yet, thank you so much!!