# At what point is the Shield (p. 275 phb) spell put into effect?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

At what point is the Shield (p. 275) spell put into effect?

The Shield spell description states “Casting Time:  1 reaction, which you take when you are HIT by an attack...”
  Does this mean that at the point when an attack is determined to have hit (in other words, after an enemy’s attack roll)  I’m able (should I choose) to use my reaction to cast Shield and thusly add +5 to my AC?   This being the case, I would wait to determine if a strike hit, consider their roll number and engage Shield if the +5 would be helpful.  Otherwise, just take the hit.
I can sense that my inexperience is causing me to miss something obvious...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast [this?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44441/do-you-have-to-cast-shield-prior-to-your-opponents-attack-roll)

Comment: @Carcer Yeah, that's more like it.  If not a dupe, then heavily related.  Greg, [does the question Carcer linked to](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/44441/do-you-have-to-cast-shield-prior-to-your-opponents-attack-roll) address your concerns?

Comment: @korvinStarmast, Carcer:   That got it.  Exactly what I was asking

Comment: Greg, we'll go ahead and mark this as a dupe, so people who ask it the same way will be pointed to where they need to look.  Thanks.  It's not hard to end up asking the same question a lot of different ways.